# How to make facebook page admin to control the settings for the custom tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-page

I have created a custom tab and made my user to install the tab by managing permissions, 
But here i want only the admin to add their own details and other users expect the admin should have the access permission to view the admin tab.

Follow this snippets: 
http://weltel.freeiz.com/testings/fb1.png

Snippet1. ![In this image, when page admin install the custom tab, it should display something like asking for the username for twitter. But the problem im facing here is after giving the username, when an user visits that twitter tab, even they are also seeing the same display. How can i make this settings particularly for the admin other-then the users][1]

Snippet2. 
http://weltel.freeiz.com/testings/fb2.png

![This should be the users display rather than the first admin snippet][2]

This is some code by which i tried but couldn't fix the problem.Im working on php..

```
    <?
require_once 'facebook.php';
$fb_app_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$fb_app_secret = "xxxxxxxxx";


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $fb_app_id,
        'secret' => $fb_app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));


// Facebook magic sauce...
$fb_signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$fb_page_id = $fb_signed_request["page"]["id"];
$fb_like_status = $fb_signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$fb_is_admin = ($fb_signed_request["page"]["admin"]==1)?TRUE:FALSE;

?>
```

Comment: what happens when you do **echo 'REQ:'.$fb_signed_request["page"]["admin"];** ?

Comment: '"<?php
 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')),   > true);

 if (empty($data["page"]["admin"])) {
    echo "You are not an admin!";
 } else {
    echo "Welcome Admin!";
 } ?>"'

I found this code, where can i redirect admin to settings link page  and non-admin or users to other link page.If so please suggest me with some code..

Comment: @GilBirman i didnt find any output with that code.
Nothing is displayed, blank.

Comment: It sounds like there is no signed request data. This might have something to do with your secure URL in your app settings, or some other basic problem. IOW, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two apps using this feature. Aplicativo Bomba Nuclear is one.. its getting all details from pages and inserting this detains into form fields .

```
   if (!empty($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
     $signedRequest = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
     list($sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signedRequest, 2);
     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
}
```